# Will existing users be able to update the app if the app is blocked in their Play Store country

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I have a published Android app open to US, Singapore and UK. There are users on app from all these countries but for content reasons I would like to block the app on Google Play to users in US and Singapore.

My question is, will users from US and Singapore still be able to download the further updates on the app from Play Store?

Comment: Actually, without reading the background of OP as developer, the same question can also apply to end-user.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, because in my country I have no access to some Google apps when I install custom ROM and want to download them, but if I use stock ROMs that come bundled with them, I can normally update them as I have them under "My Apps" in my Google account.

Think of it also from security reasons. It would be very bad if someone shipped an app with a security hole and then can't update it because it isn't available for that market.